# An ArrayList of two dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am able to declare variables dataList and data as follows:

```
ArrayList<Double[][]> dataList = new ArrayList<Double[][]>();
double [][] data = new double[2][];
```

but when I do something like

```
dataList.add(data);
```

I get an error saying

```
The method add(Double[][]) in the type ArrayList<Double[][]>
    is not applicable for the arguments (double[][])
```

How can I add data to dataList?

Comment: Beware - `double` & `Double` are 2 different things in java. You can't use them interchangeably. You are passing in a `double` when the method expects a `Double`. Lowercase version is a primitive data type and uppercase version is a class. Also, as in Ted's answer, when you create an array of primitives, you get an object.

Comment: @Takendarkk In some cases you can go from one to the other, just not this case because the question deals with arrays.

Comment: I thought the autoboxing concept might be a bit much at this time :)

Comment: Yeah, I assumed you understood. I just wanted to throw it out there.

Answer (score 4):

Declare your list to contain elements of type `double[][]` instead of `Double[][]`:

```
ArrayList<double[][]> dataList = new ArrayList<double[][]>();
```

This works because `double[][]` is not a primitive type, and hence can be the actual value for the generic type parameter for `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `ArrayList<double[][]>` as Ted explained.

```
ArrayList<double[][]> dataList = new ArrayList<double[][]>();
```

The reason for the error is, `double[][]` is itself an Object, whereas `Double[][]` is an array of references to `Double` array of references to the `Double` objects.